Which options is mke2fs -t ext4 compatible with?
I am building lineage os 17.1
Build fails at //frameworks/av/apex:com.android.media.swcodec apex (image) [common]
at the command
out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/mke2fs -O ^has_journal -b 4096 -m 0 -t ext4 -I 256 -N 106 -U 7d1522e1-9dfa-5edb-a43e-98e3a4d20250 -E hash_seed=7d1522e1-9dfa-5edb-a43e-98e3a4d20250 apex_payload.img 37M

mke2fs 1.44.4 (18-Aug-2018)
Creating regular file /home/android/lineage/17.1/out/soong/.temp/tmpRQLnjX/content/apex_payload.img
Invalid filesystem option set: has_journal,extent,huge_file,flex_bg,metadata_csum,metadata_csum_seed,64bit,dir_nlink,extra_isize,orphan_file

The mke2fs fails because of -t ext4. I am suspecting it is incompatible with one of the following options has_journal,extent,huge_file,flex_bg,metadata_csum,metadata_csum_seed,64bit,dir_nlink,extra_isize,orphan_file. Which of the option is ext4 incompatible with?

The version of mke2fs used here doesn’t support orphan_file. orphan_file support was added in version 1.47.0; presumably your system has a recent enough mke2fs, so /etc/mke2fs.conf enables the feature.
To work around this you’ll have to disable orphan_file in /etc/mke2fs.conf, run the build, and restore the option afterwards.
